# Буква I перед названием java файла

Tags: java

Для чего ставить перед название java файла букву I?
Например: IChatBaseComponent.java

Comment: Так могут делать, если , например, IChatBaseComponent является интерфейсом.

Comment: Можно ставить...а можно не ставить...зависит от соглашений. нотации разные бывают...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, таким образом создатель этого файла хотел сказать, что это интерфейс. Вообще букву I ставить необязательно.

Comment: @КириллНикифоров примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа